# Strange error on in windows Shared memory

Tags: c, windows, memory, shared-memory

I'm creating a web server in c. I wanted it multiprocess, so i needed to share some stuff between processes.

I've used shared memory, but sometimes my process crashes for a memory violation access.

The address to the shared memory may vary between process. Gdb debugging seems impossible (I've also tried to attach to the running process, still without much success).

I've downloaded the sample code from Microsoft site, tried to run it and found that at every run the pointer to memory address is different.

I have a main process, that check every few milliseconds that there are two process alive. Every process serve one client, and then dies.

The behavior is this: Sometimes, when i run the program, it crashes at the first attempt to use the shared memory. Sometimes it will require many re-spawned process to crash the program. With just one spawned process, it works well every time.

Actually this is program just a porting of a Linux server, so i don't think i'm doing something wrong with pointers elsewhere.

This is the code that creates the memory mapping on the main process:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security = { 
    sizeof(security), NULL, TRUE
};

hSharedMemory = CreateFileMapping(
             INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
             &security,               // Handle ereditabile
             PAGE_READWRITE| SEC_NOCACHE | SEC_COMMIT,          // read/write access
             0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
             region_sz,               // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
             NULL);                 // name of mapping object
if (hSharedMemory == NULL)
{
    printf("CreateFileMapping: %lu", GetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I will then pass the HANDLE with other stuff to the spawned process with a PIPE.

Then, it opens the memorymapping using:

```
ptr = MapViewOfFile(hSharedMemory,   // handle to map object
                    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                    0,
                    0,
                    region_sz);
```

I've read the msdn documentation but can't find any ideas why this happens.

On process creation, i've setted the handle inerithance argument to TRUE.

I'm on Windows 8.1 with mingw compiler.

Comment: Access violation is probably caused (99% chances) by a bug in your code. The piece of code shown is correct, so without a full repro, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I really suggest you to make gdb work or try valgrind (valgrind --leak-check=yes --trace-children=yes)

Comment: @SimonMourier thought so, but as i said this is just a porting of a linux program that works well. So i'm trying to find the bug in the diff of the two projects.

Comment: @terencehill On Linux i set gdb to set follow-fork-mode child. Anyway when the error is reached gdb dosent' show anything for some reason. I've found out it was a memory access violation thanks to VisualStudio (but didn't help more then this).

Comment: Which part of the source crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass the handle to the other process through a pipe. This does not work.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Multiple processes can share a view of the same file by either using a single shared file mapping object or creating separate file mapping objects backed by the same file. **A single file mapping object can be shared by multiple processes through** inheriting the handle at process creation, **duplicating the handle, or opening the file mapping object by name. For more information, see the** CreateProcess, **DuplicateHandle and OpenFileMapping functions.**

Also a good source of Information: [MSDN on Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683463(v=vs.85).aspx).

I suggest creating a guid and using that as `lpName` in `CreateFileMapping` and `OpenFileMapping`.

Comment: Thanks. See my edit: On process creation, i've setted the handle inerithance argument to TRUE. So isn't it enough? Or do i need to duplicate the handle anyway?

Comment: Also, i've already tried that way. In windows 7 every time i want to debug my program i need administrator permission to run the program, and crashes anyway.

Comment: @FedericoPonzi That should be sufficient, no Need to DuplicateHandle.

Comment: So i just need to send the handle value to the child process using the pipe right?

Comment: @FedericoPonzi Yes, this is how I read the MSDN article on Inheritance.